# Estimates on the number of vertices of reflexive polytopes

Tags: co.combinatorics, convex-polytopes, combinatorial-geometry, polytopes

Suppose $M \cong \mathbb{Z}^n$ is a rank $n$ lattice, with dual lattice $N$. Suppose $\Delta$ is a full dimensional lattice polytope (i.e. convex hull of finite lattice points)  in $M$. Then $\Delta$ is a reflexive polytope if and only if its dual polytope  $\Delta^\vee =\{y \in M \otimes_\mathbb{Z} \mathbb{R} \mid \langle \Delta, y \rangle \geq -1\}$ is also a lattice polytope.

Let $\#(V(\Delta))$ denote the number of vertices of $\Delta$.

Is there any estimate on $\#(V(\Delta))$? Particularly, It would be great if we have bound like $$\max\{\#(V(\Delta)\mid \Delta ~{\rm{ is~ reflexive ~of dimensional~}}n\} \leq C n$$ for some constant $C$ not depending on $n$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A "cube" $[-1,1]^n$ has $2^n$ vertices and is reflexive.

Comment: Indeed. But then excluding products of smaller reflexive polytopes, what are the known bounds ?